# Unable to test radio button in react

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I want to create a test for this react component to check that the first radio button is checked, but i got an error:

> Error: expect(element).toBeChecked()
> Received element is not checked:

```
<div>
  <h3>Please choose a fruit:</h3>
  <div>
    <div>
     <input
        id="apple"
        type="radio"
        name="fruits"
        value="Apple"
      ><label
        for="apple"
      >Apple</label>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
    <input
        id="banana"
        type="radio"
        name="fruits"
        value="Banana"
      ><label
        for="banana"
      >Banana</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Test**

```
const radioOption1 = screen.getByRole("radio", {
    name: /apple/i,
  });

  expect(radioOption1).toBeChecked();
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but does that message not just say that your test fails because the radio button is not checked?

Comment: @paddotk, yes the error is just that this radio button is not checked

Comment: To fix the error, you need to add the `checked` attribute to the `input` element. Like this: ```<input id="apple" type="radio" name="fruits" value="Apple" checked><label  for="apple">Apple</label>```

Comment: What is the question then, if it's clear your test fails?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not close the  element.

```
<div>
  <h3>Please choose a fruit:</h3>
  <div>
    <div>
     <input
        id="apple"
        type="radio"
        name="fruits"
        value="Apple"
      /><label
        for="apple"
      >Apple</label>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
    <input
        id="banana"
        type="radio"
        name="fruits"
        value="Banana"
      /><label
        for="banana"
      >Banana</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```